# How to disable mask on selected image in the f/ckeditor in webkit, opera browsers?

Tags: css, ckeditor, fckeditor

When one selects an image in the fckeditor or ckeditor in webkit browsers ( chrome, safari ) and others like opera, the image is overlaid with a transparent gray mat, presumably as a visual cue to the user that the image is selected ( reference attached images ). The problem is this makes it impossible to apply any css effects to the image efficiently within the editor. This seems to be a browser default user agent style issue, as firefox actually works as desired. How can one target, override and disable this?

[Annoying mask on image selection in editors on webkit / opera browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV1bc.png)

[Preferred image selection without mask in editor on firefox / IE browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/timUr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, looks like the answer to this is just a matter of [styling ::selection afterall.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection)